# How to fill a select with default object by ajax

Tags: javascript, object

I do have a JSON string which I receive by ajax which is correctly ordered:

```
{"label":"Gr\u00f6\u00dfe","values":{"4302":"XS","4184":"S","4185":"M","4186":"L","4187":"XL","4188":"XXL","5165":"3XL","4340":"4XL"}}
```

This JSON fills a select. The problem is, that the options are automatically reordered ( I don't know why? ) based on the value key which means that I do not get the correct option order for the select.

The option looks like:
S,M,L,XL,XXL,XS,4XL,3XL

The correct order should be 
XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL,3XL,4XL

What can I do to get the correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript there is no guaranteed order for the properties on objects. Instead, you should use an array in your JSON to ensure order. Something like this:

```
{"label":"Gr\u00f6\u00dfe","values":[{"4302":"XS"},{"4184":"S"}, ...]}
```

You can format the objects in the `values` array anyhow you'd like, but the idea is when concerned with order, use arrays.

Comment: It's better to have `"values":[{"key": "4302", "value":"XS"...}]`

Comment: Hence my comment "you can format the objects in the values array anyhow you'd like"